# Item add in bottom of drop down list with value field

Tags: asp.net

how i can add item in bottom whenever i am bind the gridview dynamic.
and i want a value field. because i have a search criteria with drop down list. 
With Drop Down List Value I am sending the value with drop down list .

SqlParameter[] param3 = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@status","org")
            };

```
        ddlDistrictCode.DataSource = comnFunctionObj.getDropDownList(clsConstant.GET_ALL_DROPDOWN, param3);
        ddlDistrictCode.DataTextField = "DisplayFieldText";
        ddlDistrictCode.DataValueField = "ValueFieldText";
        ddlDistrictCode.DataBind();
```

**Search Criteria**

By this I am sending the value

new SqlParameter("@DISTRICTCODE",Convert.ToInt32((ddlDistrictCode.SelectedValue))),

Comment: can you describe whats happening.. or can you show the code that you tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

After you databind, just add the value manually:

```
ddlDistrictCode.Items.Insert(lst.Items.Count - 1, new ListItem("VALUE", "TEXT"));
```